# how can I get response in array not string by axios.get in react native?

Tags: php, react-native, axios

I connect to db by php code,I wrote some code to get data with axios.get in react native. But response from axios.get is string not array.

I tried eval(response) and JSON.parse(response) but I can not convert response to array.

**here is my react native code, it is writen in componentDidMount**

```
const mobile = "0912111111";

const data = {

      mobile: mobile
   };
   var headers = {

        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.3/Account/family_manage.php',{data:data}, 
    {headers:headers})
    .then((response) => {

   //how to convert response to array of array here
   console.log(eval(response).data);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    Alert.alert('error');
    console.log(error);
    });
```

**here is my code in php backend:**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
include "connect.php";

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$mobile=$obj['mobile'];

$sql = "SELECT box_name,num_box FROM family_box WHERE 
admin_mobile='$mobile'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

          $myarr[] =array('name'=> $row['box_name'],'num'=>$row['num_box']);
     }


    echo json_encode($myarr);
 } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }

 mysqli_close($conn);
```

How can I get array of array response and How can I access to 'name' or num in response data?
thanks

Comment: you can try this return
 response ()->json('name'=>$myarr, 'num'=>$myarr2);

Comment: It did'nt work correctly, this syntax is incorrect.

Comment: add line in top header one
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return response()->json($data);

Comment: ,{data:data}, 
    {headers:headers}) are you sending data to server ?

Comment: yes, it send correctly and return correct response but response is string not array of obect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in axis you don't need to convert data into stringify it can automatically done by this you can directly use this like `this.setState({response:response})`
and if you want to see that data into onscreen for check you can also check by `console.warn(response)`

here's an example that I used for my app

```
  async function getshoppinapi(link) {
      let responseJson = await axios.get(link,{ headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${global.token}`} })
      //let responseJson = response;
      return responseJson;
}
```

Comment: I used `this.setState({response:response})` but response is string. my result is same as `[{"name":"box20","num":"57"},{"name":"box21","num":"58"}]`, how can I change it to array of objects?

Comment: @MahmonirBakhtiyari result already is in string format you just use it. use flatlist or sectionlist for show your data